# What editor is as good as TextPad for compiling and running Java programs?

Tags: software-recommendation, java, programming, text-editor, ide

I want an editor that is as good as TextPad (for Windows) for compiling and running Java programs on Ubuntu 12.04. Please suggest one.

Comment: Please write a bit more about what features you need and maybe what you don't like in other editors you have seen so far. That would make it much easier to suggest programs that fit your needs, even for people not knowing Textpad.

Comment: i want features like:-  1> compile and run from the editor  2> Syntax highlighting  3> want to see the actual errors notifications from JVM.  Currently i am using eclipse but it's very user friendly (ctrl + k ) does all the job.

Comment: As mentioned by @Yems, NetBeans is as powerful as Eclipse, and it covers exactly your needs on 1> Compiling and running from the editor, 2> Syntax errors highligting, 3> JVM actual errors notifications. I was about to suggest you the NetBeans but Yems did it already.

Comment: thanks for the information; but i want a lightweight text editor with same functionality and some keyboard shortcuts would be very helpful.  Like if could configure vi/vim to recognize java syntax and compile and run the programs with some keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Geany](http://www.geany.org/Main/HomePage)

From the official site:

> Geany is a text editor using the GTK2 toolkit with basic features of
>   an integrated development environment. It was developed to provide a
>   small and fast IDE, which has only a few dependencies from other
>   packages. It supports many filetypes and has some nice features.

[image: Screenshot from the official site]

---

## [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/)

Additionally, [**jEdit**](http://www.jedit.org/) [***(man page)***](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/jedit.1.html) seems to be another excellent option for your tasks.

From the man site:

> jEdit   is  a  cross-platform  text  editor  written in Java. It has
>   an extensive feature set that includes syntax highlighting,  auto 
>   indent, folding,   word  wrap,  abbreviation  expansion,  multiple 
>   clipboards, powerful search and replace and much more.
>
> Furthermore, jEdit is extremely  customizable,  and  extensible, 
>   using either  macros  written in the BeanShell scripting language, or
>   plugins written  in  Java.  With  plugins,  you  can  create  a  very 
>   powerful development environment for HTML, XML, C/C++, Python, Perl,
>   Ruby, Lisp, Scheme, and many others.
>
> jEdit Requires Sun Java 2 version 1.5.
>
> jEdit is released under the GNU General Public License,  which  can 
>   be found in the online help.

[image: Screenshot from the official site]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)!
It have a lot of documentation in diferent languages and it's a wonderfull IDE

[image]

Comment: I use Eclipse everything for work, and i haven't found a better IDE to date.

Comment: Don't use Mars if you are into Android development though. It [crashes terribly](https://www.prahladyeri.com/blog/2015/12/eclipse-mars-not-ready-for-linux.html) on my ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

[IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), a fully fledged Java IDE by Jetbrains, has gained a lot of traction during the recent years. It provides integration with many common frameworks and tools like Git, Web development, Java application servers and Android.

[image: official IntelliJ screenshot]

I consider it to be a worthy successor to Eclipse, which has become slow and collected a lot of cruft and asinine behaviour.

IntelliJ IDEA “Community Edition” is free, open-source software (and the base for the “Ultimate Edition” which includes a bunch of features based on closed-source, proprietary extensions geared towards professional collaborative software development with larger code bases).

Answer (score 2):

Look, there is an IDE called NetBeans in which you can edit, compile and run Java programs. This program is for editing in java. I've tried it on Ubuntu 11.10 without any complication for University homework and I have read that it runs natively on 12.04

[image]

NetBeans includes its own editor which has several features useful for programming, download it in: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Sorry my English, I am using a translator since my native language is the Spanish. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Notepad ++ is a better notepad.  You could also look for eclipse or Netbeans for java editting.

Here are links for eclipse which is what I use:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
I use the classic version but have the EE installed as well

Comment: isn't it only for windows?

Comment: @Web-E It runs well in Ubuntu [with Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2983). I still prefer a native editor, but I haven't had any problems with Notepad++ via Wine (though apparently [some features don't work](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25722)).

Comment: WINE is a second-class citizen in linux world, and should only be resorted to if NO other alternative is available. In this case, there are a plethora of native editors in linux world. I used to be a Notepad++ fan earlier, but found that with a [little bit of tweaking](https://www.prahladyeri.com/blog/2015/11/how-to-add-html-tag-highlighting-geany.html), Geany can surpass Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

[Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), of course.

Install with:

```
sudo apt install emacs
```