# What's a text editor for Linux that can compile and run without the use of Terminal?

Tags: java, compiling, text-editor

I'm looking for a text editor that can compile and run .java files directly, without having to use `javac filename.java` and `java filename`. Something similar would be Textpad for Windows, which uses ctrl+1 to compile and ctrl+2 to run.

I've been using gedit for a while, but I find that Textpad is so much easier. What is a program for Linux (preferably free) that offers this feature?

I also don't want an IDE, just a simple text editor with keyboard shortcuts. I have tried Eclipse and Netbeans and found them too unwieldy for my tastes.

Comment: Since I typically have several terms open anyways, I usually don't use the terminal feature in the vim editor. But you can execute shell commands from within the vim editor itself, as I understand it. I don't use emacs, but I understand it has a fairly slick shell ability itself. Not sure about the java requirement, but I'm looking at it as more of a 'generic' shell command anyway.

Comment: That still leaves Geany and jEdit.

Comment: So vim or Geany can use keyboard shortcuts (or some other shortcut) to compile and run?

Comment: Geany can, and Vim can be configured to do so.

Comment: Geany is pretty outdated, but might work.  Vim has a horrible learning curve that makes it a waste of time for most people.

Comment: @Goddard outdated by what standards?

Comment: I think you just want to argue @muru.  If you want to talk to me we can discuss this in #ubuntu-offtopic in irc.  I have the same name as on here.

Comment: @Goddard No, I'm genuinely curious. The last release of Geany was on [November 15th](http://www.geany.org/Documentation/ReleaseNotes). [The version on Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=geany) is as updated as can be expected from a normal package. And we have [chat] here.

Comment: Chatting on AskUbuntu comments is discouraged.  Lets try and take this to a chat if you want to talk further as we shouldn't hijack the op's question.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans works well.  You can install it easily by going to the website, or

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

You can also use Eclipse by either downloading it from the site, or using the repos.

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

They are both open source as well.

Comment: Both are mentioned in [the dupe](http://askubuntu.com/questions/167256/what-editor-is-as-good-as-textpad-for-compiling-and-running-java-programs).

Comment: That's perfect.

Comment: I actually don't want an IDE,  I edited my question. Sorry that I forgot to mention that.

Comment: You could use Atom, although I don't know if it has any Java compilation plugins.  Atom is just as slow as an IDE though.  Sublime Text might have a plugin for it, but it is closed source and tracks you.  I doubt you will get any more input here.  @muru will down vote anyone who answers you.

Comment: @Goddard I will if they're just replicating answers.

Comment: I know I just said that.

Comment: Nope. You said I will downvote *anyone*. I won't downvote someone who's providing new information.

Comment: Well then bud you should re-read what you posted because my answer is not the same - http://askubuntu.com/questions/167256/what-editor-is-as-good-as-textpad-for-compiling-and-running-java-programs

Comment: No, there's nothing new, "bud".

Comment: haha take a chill pill.  I just don't see it the same as you.  No need to get all upset.